# elastic search fuzzy query strange results

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I'm use elastic search for about one month and i've found one thing one query fuzzie that i can't understand.

The scenario is i've a set of users on a type and index almost 10.000 items, and i want to search for username, and return all the items that match with search string in a fuzzy mode, for example my user is "masterviana" if i search by only with text "mastervi" i expect to see the masterviana at the top of results using a fuzzy query right?

```
"fuzzy" : {
    "public_name" : {
        "value" :         "mastervi",
        "boost" :         1.0,
        "fuzziness" :     2,
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions": 100
    }
}
```

However i'm not seeing my username (masterviana) at the first page and also i see usernames that are "less similar" like my query string, i'll show the only the first 5 hits for not extended to much the post

```
 {
            "_index": "username",
            "_type": "username",
            "_id": "2061|FZ4y1t042482S3EqobiVllmv00",
            "_score": 9.198499,
            "_source": {
                "public_name": "masterv",
                "bbid": "FZ4y1t042482S3EqobiVllmv00",
                "hash": 2061,
                "avata": "http://goo.gl/4CRt3v"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "username",
            "_type": "username",
            "_id": "2048|r0I5XZ31076phruMS1gu9Hjv00",
            "_score": 5.9688096,
            "_source": {
                "public_name": "project--master",
                "bbid": "r0I5XZ31076phruMS1gu9Hjv00",
                "hash": 2048,
                "avata": "http://goo.gl/4CRt3vr"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "username",
            "_type": "username",
            "_id": "1980|W5Wal166832UV5oCqUH9Vjcv00",
            "_score": 5.7984095,
            "_source": {
                "public_name": "masterjv",
                "bbid": "W5Wal166832UV5oCqUH9Vjcv00",
                "hash": 1980,
                "avata": "http://goo.gl/4CRt3v"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "username",
            "_type": "username",
            "_id": "2108|Kufhm899338GPWHsuoei1HOv00",
            "_score": 5.7984095,
            "_source": {
                "public_name": "master25",
                "bbid": "Kufhm899338GPWHsuoei1HOv00",
                "hash": 2108,
                "avata": "http://goo.gl/4CRt3v"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "username",
            "_type": "username",
            "_id": "1952|AtPw2a97575sC5JT406msOXv00",
            "_score": 5.7984095,
            "_source": {
                "public_name": "masterpiz",
                "bbid": "AtPw2a97575sC5JT406msOXv00",
                "hash": 1952,
                "avata": "http://goo.gl/4CRt3v"
            }
        },
```

AS you can see i'm getting at top 1. masterv 2. project-master i think my query "mastervi" is more close to "masterviana" that for example "masterv" or "project-master"

One more thing if i search with exactly the same text "masterviana" i'm getting only this item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranking is a blend of edit distance and (often unhelpfully) how rare a term is.
I'm not sure which of these is to blame in this case but the term scarcity ranking is a long-standing Lucene issue. There is a work-around in elasticsearch with FuzzyLikeThisQuery but that might not be around for much longer so this has accelerated the need to fix Lucene (see here for background https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10391 )

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i see what are saying however even if i use for fuzzyLikeThis i'm not seeing my username too. i'm using like this "fuzzy_like_this" : {
       "fields" : ["public_name"],
        "like_text" : "mastervi"
    }
but same things was happening, is there is a way of doing this while this issue are solved?

Comment: The _explain API can help reveal the detailed scoring logic behind individual matches. FuzzyLikeThis should have removed scarcity from the equation but mastervi is technically closer to mastervi than masterviana because it is only one character change in terms of Levenstein edit distance measures